# Why is my HTML document being scrambled when using FSharp.Data HTML parser?

Tags: html, parsing, f#, f#-data

When trying to manipulate some HTML with the FSharp.Data library I am getting confusing results.

Here is the code:

```
let manipulateHtml (htmlDoc:HtmlDocument) =
    htmlDoc.Html().Descendants()
    |> filterFromHtml stuffToRemove 
    |> HtmlDocument.New
```

When I print the resulting Html document it is not in the correct order - it seems to reconstruct the document starting from a random node. How does HtmlDocument.New(seq) reconstruct the html document and is there a way to reconstruct the document in the correct format - e.g. its original order?

Comment: Interesting - well, `Descendants()` is technically a `seq` which is like `IEnumerable` and does not guarantee to follow the order. Have you tried inserting `|> Seq.toList` before filtering?

Comment: The problem persists even if I convert to a list

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `Descendants()` method returns all the children in a recursive manner. This means the returned sequence will contain all the grandparent, parent, children ... nodes.

For example, when the doc is:

```html
<html>
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
            this is the text
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
</html>
```

Then `Descendants()` will return a sequence of nodes like this:

```html
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        this is the text
    </tag2>
</tag1>

<tag2>
    this is the text
</tag2>

this is the text
```

But the `HtmlDocument.New` method constructs the doc in a flat manner, so you will have a doc look like above with `tag2` repeated twice, and `this is the text` repeated 3 times.

So in order to solve your problem, you need to traverse the tree of `htmlDoc.Html()`, determine which node would be retained, and in the meanwhile construct a new tree using the `HtmlNode.New***()` and `HtmlDocument.New***()` methods.

Comment: Do you know if the library provides a way to traverse the dom in a non-recursive or flat way?

Comment: `elements` will get you the nodes below. Or you could use `HtmlAgilityPack`, it supports XPath, etc.

Comment: I think the problem was actually that the console provided by visual studio can only display a certain number of lines. This cut off the result while I was debugging making it appear as though the nodes were starting from a random place. Descendants works fine.